# how to attach a toArray function to a interface property?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Consider this setup.

```
interface C {
  foo: string
}
interface A {
  B: Record<string, C>
  // ... some more properties
}
const test: A = {
  B: { hi: {foo: "hello"} }
  // ... some more properties
}
```

now I want to be able to do

```
test.B.toArray()
```

that would do

```
Object.values(test.B)
```

Now here's a partial solution I came up with that I'm not satisfied with.

```
interface C {
  foo: string;
}
interface A {
  B: { value: Record<string, C>; toArray: () => Array<C> };
}

const test: A = {
  B: {
    value: { hi: { foo: "hello" } },
    toArray: function (): Array<C> {
      return Object.values(this.value);
    },
  },
};

//Why I am not happy with this solution is I now have to refer to
test.B
// as 
test.B.value
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to write the type or how to write the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `&` you will be able to say that you want the interface also implement a function.

```ts
interface A {
  B: Record<string, C & { toArray: () => Array<C> }>
  // ... some more properties
}
```

Comment: Hmm, did you test it? I'm not able to get it to work. It says cannot find name toArray.

Comment: @SreeChandan no I am unfortunately coding on tablet (awful experience), forgot braces. This should do it.

Comment: sure no prob. Thanks to you now I came to know of intersection types. I'll try to figure this out myself